# Sharing class and database with Share extension

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension, share-extension

I am trying to share class and database from my app to app extension . I have tried to add classes from the TARGET Membership, but on adding following issue comes[image: UIApplication.sharedApplication()]

Could any one help me to access my class and database in share extension.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To access `UIApplication` object you must import the `UIKit` framework like:

```
import UIKit
```

or if you only want to import `UIApplication` class you can write

```
import class UIKit.UIApplication
```

Also note that if you want to use `CoreData` in your Share extension, you will need to create new container and set the `storeURL` to point to created container.